# Output screen is empty in this program

Tags: c, string

I wrote a program to check the frequency of numbers from 0 to 9  in a given input STRING e.g "abc12af1479" here '0' does not occur, '1' occurs 2 times and so on. The printf statement that i wrote for count is not working is something wrong here or my logic is wrong?

```
int main()
{

char ch[1000], s[10]={'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
int i, j, count;
gets(ch);

for(i=0; s[i]<10; i++)
{
    count=0;
    for(j=0; ch[j] != '\0'; j++)
    {
        if(ch[j]==s[i])
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d ", count);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `s[i]<10` should be `i<10`

Comment: You probably also want to change your printf into `printf("%d: %d\n", i, count)` so that you can see the value counted and you print one result per line. Just a suggestion. If you want to keep every count in sequence on the same line, then a `printf("\n")` after the loop would end the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for (i = 0; s[i] < 10; i++)
```

In this case, `s[0]` is the `char` `'0'`, which will likely have a value that's greater than `10`. In [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) it is `48`, so `s[i] < 10;` is always false and the loop never runs. Instead, change this loop to:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

Comment: Thank You Sir, Problem solved i was a little confused, didn't noticed it